Image polygon detection from image
I am looking for a polygon detection library in Python that isn't an implementation in OpenCV via edge detectors and contours (this gives me unsatisfactory results).
In OpenCV I used grayscale Canny edge detector with finding contours and their approximation, but there are quite a lot of artifacts and some huge objects aren't detected at all.
I tried this process with various values for cv.Canny(), cv.approxPolyDP and also Gaussian blurring and/or dilatation.
The desired result should mostly detect quadrangles and triangles: doors, windows and roofs.
The original picture 1:

The desired result 1 (roof, doors and windows detected):

The OpenCV result 1:

The original picture 2:

The desired result 2:

The OpenCV result 2:


this might need AI. semantic segmentation. or maybe "just" superpixels or graph cuts or whatever, but those aren't terribly semantic. -- you ought to explain the goal/purpose. -- simple low level Canny will never give you what you want. do not touch Canny or Hough.

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you for the response, the further application of these will be the overall areas of all the "important" polygonial features: area of the doors, windows, the facade and the roof.

since that's all "image space", it will not give you measurements correlating to true area... unless you have length references in the view and you correct for the perspective (homography). you might want to approach this with 3D scans (point clouds or some surface model) and apply semantic segmentation to that. this is a lot of theory and implementation. it could be a research project.

@ChristophRackwitz The idea behind the calculations is certainly by the length references since the doors in the images in the most images will have some dimensions based on the doors available on the market (mostly 200×90 cm, but can be e.g. 200×80 cm or 200×100 cm), hence the algorithm should be able to detect the door dimensions based on the aspect ratio of the polygon lines lengths, shouldn't it?
And to clarify, this is a bachelor's thesis project.

I'm not sure of that math. given a rectangle model and a quad resulting from a perspective projection of it, that's barely enough info to recover the pose. I don't know if it's enough to also disambiguate between rects of differing aspect ratios. against a given quad, you can get a pose estimation for arbitrary rectangle models... I think. you're in a better position to work out the math and prove or disprove this. or just try it on a set of synthetic data. make up a random (plausible) quad, then see what cv::solvePnP() does when you give it point sets of two different rects to fit against.

ok so I tried the solvepnp experiment. it looks like there isn't an arbitrary RT that makes the wrong model match perfectly, i.e. you can probably disambiguate door aspect ratios with this. the results I get are very marginal though. using synthetic data (ideals), both a 1:1 and a 2:1 aspect ratio map with similar error to a trapezoid I came up with (dy=180, dx=180..220). you'll need really solid estimates of the quad. I'm not sure it's all that feasible after all.

You may want to mess with the threshold1, and threshold2 as documented here. These are the hyperparameters for noise reduction. Below, I manually tune the thresholds and you can see these give different result.


Another thing you can do is that, considering you said you grayscaled the image. Well, in that case, if you do grayscale, neighbouring pixels of different colours but happen to have just the same amount of brightness are just not detected at all (say, a red pixel and a green pixel probably have just the same amount of brightness, so viewed under grayscale then they just look the same). The purpose of grayscaling the image is technically just to downgrade the image into one channel (instead of 3 channels: red, green, and blue). Therefore one thing you can try to do to downgrade the image is that, first convert from RGB to HSL, then apply Canny onto the Hue channel.
Hope this helps!

Your answer doesn't address the example given by OP, please re-adjust and actually show that your answer solves some of the problems that OP is encountering
